# Require once php function and variables

Tags: php, function, variables, require

I am looking for some help using the PHP function. At the moment my website is structured like this:

index.php:

```
<?php   
require_once( 'page_elements.php' );
?>
<body>

<?php echo content();?>

</body>
```

page_elements.php:

```
<?php
function content() {
?>
<div class='main'> 
  <img class='main' src="<?=$ImgName?>"> </img> 
</div>
<?php
} ?>
```

if statement:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['basket_total']))
{

$basket_total = $_SESSION['basket_total'];

if($basket_total !== '0')
{

    $ImgName = 'img/basket.php';    

}
else
{

    $ImgName = 'img/basket_empty.php';

}
}
```

What I want to do is to be able to define $ImgName in an if statement that isn't involved in the function content() but if i include it in another file, include 'if_statement.php' or in another function then it doesn't recognise the variable.

Sorry, its my first time structuring a website like this and I am finding it a bit confusing.

Cheers in advance

Comment: You should look at a framework, you're going down the wrong path.  I would recommend CodeIgniter for you

Comment: Yii MVC is better; pls paste the code with your variable; i will help you see get the code you ask; i did not understand the details;

Comment: Ya, everyone has their preferences. I think Kohana is better, but I wasn't arguing which was best, I recommended one that has the best documentation to make it as easy as possible for this guy. YII MVC IS BETTER! YA!

Comment: I would disagree recommending a frameworks straight away. He would be better served figuring out the basics first before adding on the learning curve of a framework.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't close an an "img" tag with another "img" tag ...

```
function content(){
    echo'
    <div class="main">
        <img class="main" src="'.$imgname.'" alt="" title="">
    </div>
    ';
}
```

is the proper way of doing things. Now as to your question, I'm having trouble understanding your goal, but do you perhaps mean something a.la ...

```
function content(){
    $imgname = include "file.php";
    echo'
    <div class="main">
        <img class="main" src="'.$imgname.'" alt="" title="">
    </div>
    ';
}
```

and the if_statement.php would be something like ...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['basket_total'])){
    return $_SESSION['basket_total'];
}else{
    return "img/basket.php";
}
```

Comment: or pass the value as argument

Comment: @ChrisGastrell thank you very much for your answer. I can see it working but can you please give me more details of what the file.php would include given the if statement i gave in my original question?  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will get around the current issue you are having, but I would do like Ionut Flavius Pogacian suggested above and look into an MVC

```
<?php   
    require_once( 'page_elements.php' );
    $image_name = "batman.jpg";
?>
<body>
    <?php echo content($image_name);?>
</body>
```

page_elements.php:

```
<?php
function content($image_name) {
?>
<div class='main'> 
  <img class='main' src="<?=$image_name?>" /> 
</div>
<?php
} ?>
```